# In Xcode, why are there more/less views depending on what device is running in the simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, uiview

I am having an issue where aspect fill is working on iPhones, but doesn't work on iPads except for iPad 7th generation. In the process of debugging, when I looked at the "Debug View Hierarchy", I noticed that some devices had a WindowView and a UIView behind my UIImageView while others had more views such as UITransitionView, UIDropShaddowView, and one had 2 UIViews. Why is that and why is it not consistent on all devices? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how your app is built up, but different UIKit controls can result in very different view hierarchies depending on the display size of your app. For example a UISplitViewController might end up being a simple navigation view stack (with much less views involved) on iPhone in portrait vs. an actual split view controller on iPad.

View hierarchies may also differ if you're running different OS versions across your devices, simply because implementation details of the system frameworks changed.